# Bootstrap Images and elements not rendering when using Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap and Angular and am taking an online course in Angular currently.

I'm following the examples to the letter but there is a difference between what shows up in the instructors videos and what shows up in my browser. For example, with this code:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li [class.active]="viewMode == 'map'"><a (click)="viewMode = 'map'">Map View</a></li>
<li [class.active]="viewMode == 'list'"><a (click)="viewMode = 'list'">List View</a></li>
</ul>
<div [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
<div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">Map View Content</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">List View Content</div>
<div *ngSwitchDefault>Otherwise</div>
</div>
```

I get an output of:

[image]

When the instructor enters the code he gets:

[image]

Did I download the wrong package of Bootstrap? As I understand it the class "nav nav-pills" is what should make it display the way the instructor has it.

Here is what my HTML looks like after adding the Bootstrap Schema:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the CSS imported correctly

Comment: I just checked my version of the page and the Bootstrap CSS is in there. Should there be more than one Bootstrap CSS file?

Comment: No just one CSS and one JS file. Is the JS file in there too?

Comment: I don't see a Bootstrap.js file. How to I go about getting that included?

Comment: You may not need it right now, look at my answer. You'll probably need it in the future though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example add these classes

*nav-item* to the `li` elements

*nav-link* to the `a` tags

Like in this example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

add [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) schema to your project using this `angular-cli`  command:

```bsh
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Comment: I added an updated image of my HTML after following your instructions.